# how to debug line break issues with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm maintaining this website that accepts multi-line inputs from user and sends the data via JSON. line break \n are decoded and encoded properly but somehow the \r chars are not accepted on the server side and I have the feeling I would need to escape them prior to sending them over. Before making the fix, I want to try to reproduce the issue but I can't find a way to do it !!!!

Do you have any recommendations?

**EDIT** after more investigation, it turns out that the issue is in IE only ( as in the \r chars get added when copying/pasting to the text input). Hijacking the text area did not change anything in FF or chrome and doing a data.description.replace("\r","") did not solve the issue either. Still poking around.

Comment: Do you have any code that you could post?

Comment: The way I've always handled that kind of thing is to keep the newline characters, but just remove all of the carriage-return (`\r`) characters. This might work for you, depending on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to reproduce the error, just add some js to populate the textarea:

`document.getElementById('textarea-id').value = 'test\r\ntest';`

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome's Developer Tool's Javascript](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview&ei=kUE-ULKmEKzM6QHRy4CYDg&usg=AFQjCNGeyBcJRaZkKlI2mtA1ROibAEsV2Q&sig2=rYbkhg_umR1rste2SeQrKw) Console lets you send JSON to your server using friendly jQuery/MooTools/Protoype syntax